# C++ - lambda expression, capture clause and class members

Tags: c++, lambda, parallel-processing, ppl

I am using PPL and parallel_for syntax to have a for loop. In the capture clause, I have 3 variables, one of them is a class member. There is a compilation error due to the presence of a class member among variables in the capture clause. However, if I have this class member in lambda body, it does not compile either, and error stated is that variable in enclosing scope should be in capture clause. How to proceed? Should I copy the variable member to a local variable beforehand, and have it passed in the capture clause?

Here is the code, with formulaCommand the class member.

```
parallel_for (m_rowStart,m_rowEnd+1,[&functionEvaluation,varModel_,formulaCommand](int i)
    {       
            MLEquationVariableModel  model_(varModel_);
            model_.addVariable("i", i);
            model_.addVariable("j", 1);
            MLEquationCommand* command_ = formulaCommand->duplicate(&model_);
            double d = command_->execute().toDouble();
            if(d==NO_VALUE)
            {
                functionEvaluation.local()  = NO_VALUE;
            }
            else
            {
                functionEvaluation.local() += d;
            }
            delete command_;
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to capture `this` to access the member variables (remember that `formulaCommand` is equivalent to `this->formulaCommand`).

```
[&functionEvaluation, varModel_, this](int i) { ... }
```

(BTW, you should probably use a smart pointer (`unique_ptr<MLEquationCommand>`) instead of manually `delete`-ing the raw pointer `command_`.)

Comment: Also worth noting that member variables are always captured by-reference since they are really accessed through the captured version of `this`. If you want to capture a member by value, then copy it to a local and then capture that by value.

Comment: Or like this : `[&functionEvaluation, varModel_, =]`

Comment: @KennyTM Could you expand on use of `unique_ptr<>`, or point at some relevant ref? thanks

Comment: @VJovic: The correct syntax for that would be `[=, &functionEvaluation]`.

Comment: You know what I meant, and is even shorter :)